# Display an Array of Objects by an API javascript (for loop vs for in loop)

Tags: javascript, api

I am new to js, and i came across with a quizz project. I am using this api in order to get randmom questions, and their answer `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10`

In my code below, i have succesfully display the information that i want, but my QUESTION is this the right way? i KNOW it's somthing simple but i would like to hear an opinion on if i use correctly the `for loop` or i shoud use the `for in loop`

```js
const urlApi = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";

    async function trivia(){

        const response = await fetch(urlApi);
        const data = await response.json();
        //console.log(data);
        
        let text = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++){

            text += data.results[i].category + "<br>"
            + data.results[i].correct_answer + "<br>"
            + data.results[i].difficulty + "<br>"
            + data.results[i].incorrect_answers + "<br>"
            + data.results[i].question + "<br><br><br>"
        }


        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }

    trivia();
```

```html
<div>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: This is something that depends with what you want to do.. i don't think that it's right or false

Comment: use a `for in` loop when  you want to iterate over properties of an object. If you want to loop over an array you can use the loop you're using or you can use a `for of` loop or even a `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall you code looks fine, but I find [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) useful in this case. And then combine it with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for tuning it into a string.

```js
const urlApi = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";

async function trivia() {
  const response = await fetch(urlApi);
  const data = await response.json();
  
  let text = data.results.map(question => `${question.category}<br>
    ${question.correct_answer}<br>
    ${question.difficulty}<br>
    ${question.incorrect_answers}<br>
    ${question.question}<br><br>`).join('');

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

trivia();
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. [`Array.forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) would also work.

Comment: i think you are right sometimes all you have to do is maybe "keep it simple" ?

Answer (score 1):

Fasted way of loop in js:-

**1.**

```
var i = 0, l = TemArray.length;
    while (i < l) {
        // your code
        i++
    }
```

**2.**

```
 for(let i = 0; i < TemArray.length; i++){
}
```

Also as People use `forEach` alot so whats the diffrence ??
Simple Answer :- forEach method passes a callback function for each element of an array and also easier to read compared to traditional for loop.